# PlayStore crash ClassNotFoundException after upgrading to androidX

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, classnotfoundexception, androidx

I am getting a crash in playstore after upgrading to androidX with the following stack trace

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3960)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400 (ActivityThread.java:268)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1993)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7811)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1068)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
  at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateReceiver (AppComponentFactory.java:110)
  at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateReceiver (CoreComponentFactory.java:54)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3953)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400 (ActivityThread.java:268)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1993)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7811)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1068)
```

These are the devices I am getting the crash on

```
Galaxy A30 (a30)
moto g(6) plus (evert_n)
OnePlus 7 (OnePlus7)
Galaxy Note9 (crownlte)
OnePlus 7T Pro 5G (OnePlus7TProNR)
```

Distribution URL in gradle-wrapper.properties is 5.6.4

I have upgraded by adding the following in gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

I have already tried including the following in proguard all androidX classes I was using directly

```
-keep class androidx.core.** { *; }
-keep interface androidx.core.** { *; }

-keep class androidx.annotation.** { *; }
-keep interface androidx.annotation.** { *; }

-keep class androidx.fragment.** { *; }
-keep interface androidx.fragment.** { *; }

-keep class androidx.appcompat.** { *; }
-keep interface androidx.appcompat.** { *; }

-keep class androidx.core.** { *; }
-keep interface androidx.core.** { *; }

-keep class androidx.recyclerview.** { *; }
-keep interface androidx.recyclerview.** { *; }

-keep class androidx.drawerlayout.** { *; }
-keep interface androidx.drawerlayout.** { *; }

-keep class androidx.loader.** { *; }
-keep interface androidx.loader.** { *; }
```

EDIT : I added this to my proguard file

```
-keep class * { public private *; }
```

But I still see the error

Comment: `at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)` added `multidexenabled` ?

Comment: Yes multiDexEnabled true is set. I am trying to figure out if this an issue with proguard. I have removed all dontwarn s from my proguard file

Comment: for test case add `-keep class * {
   public private *;
}`

Comment: What do you mean by test case? Adding this would mean no class will be deobfuscated right?

Comment: if working then i sure proguard issue

Comment: No I still see the crash after this, so I guess we can rule out proguard as the issue?